# Rails Routes: Programmatically extract params from a URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I need to programmatically extract the params from a URL, ie the hash that the controller would receive if the URL was called. This is not happening inside the controller, it's for an introspection tool, so the controller is never run. I want to predict what would happen if the controller was run, hopefully using the same API Rails itself is using.

For example, given a Rails route `/blogs/:id` and a URL query of `/blogs/123?published=true`, I want to extract `{ id: 123, published: true }`.

Using `Rails.application.routes.recognize_path`, I can get the `id` in this example as it's part of the route pattern, but not the extra CGI param (`published`). I could manually add those, but I'd like to know if there's a proper API for this.

Comment: Are you not getting all these as `params` inside an action?

Comment: No, I know the basic of params but this needs to be done programmatically. Updated the question to clarify that.

Comment: based on your comment on an answer below? are you looking to run this as a Rack App?  Does it need to sit in front of the controller? will it be run in production?  Or is it more simulating / gathering metadata about that app?

Comment: Just gathering metadata. It's primarily needed for a batch controller that lets callers multiplex a bunch of calls together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse the URL, read the query string and convert them to hash.

```
u = URI.parse("http://localhost:3000/blogs/213?published=true")
cgi_params = u.query.split('&').map { |e| e.split('=') }.to_h
```

Merge them with `params` that you got using `Rails.application.routes.recognize_path`

Answer (score 1):

The `params` Hash contains all the route parameters, including the query parameters.

```
# Given /blogs/123?published=true
def action
  params[:id] # => 123
  params[:published] # => "true"
end
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for an introspection tool where the controller isn't actually run.